# How can I optionally pass one or two semicolon separated params in a GET request and retrieve the data that pertains to it/them?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

In Postman, whenever I pass key `isbns` and `value`s `0307951529;9780307951526` while doing `dd($queryArray);`.  I get the correct output:

```
^ array:2 [
  "isbn10" => "0307951529"
  "isbn13" => "9780307951526"
]
```

However, on the `isbns` key, when I try to pass one `value` in Postman instead of two - I get an error that says: `array_combine(): Argument #1 ($keys) and argument #2 ($values) must have the same number of elements`.  This is because I'm being reliant on `array_combine($keysArray, $valuesArray);` to do this but I feel like it's not a good approach.

What's a good way to do this so that optionally, one or two semicolon separated values can be accepted so an error won't get thrown?

**Note:** `dd(urldecode($request->fullUrl()));` displays the url correctly (provided this detail in case more information is needed).

```
    $isbn = $request->get('isbns');
    $keysArray = ['isbn10', 'isbn13'];
    $valuesArray = explode(';', $isbn);
    $queryArray = array_combine($keysArray, $valuesArray);

    $queryParams = [
        'api-key' => $apiKey,
        'author' => $author,
        'title' => $title,
        'isbns' => [(object) $queryArray]
    ];

    dd($queryParams);
    // dd(urldecode($request->fullUrl()));
```

Comment: If you pass one value. Is it for `isbn10` or `isbn13`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto it won't let me pass one value.  I get the aforementioned error.  I'm trying to make it so that one or two values, whether or not separated by a semicolon, would suffice.

Comment: The question was, if you _were_ to only pass one value - then how is your system supposed to know, whether this value is meant for isbn10 or isbn13?

Comment: I made it simpler. What are your expectations like? Does it need to be validated so that when there is 1 data it becomes invalid, or can it still receive 1 data?

Comment: Is it also possible to pass 3 or more parameters, like `123123;324345;56778;` If so it that valid and what should happen to the third parameter if it is

Comment: It seems you don't really know what you really want.

Comment: If you want the passing of only one value to mean, that only the array element with key `isbn10` needs to be populated - then you can count how man elements `$valuesArray` contains after the explode. Then you "shorten" your `$keysArray` to that amount of elements, using `array_slice` - and then `array_combine` will work again, without complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to know what to do if only one param is passed in `isbn` then you can do this

```
$isbn = '234234;777777';
$keysArray = ['isbn10', 'isbn13'];
$valuesArray = explode(';', $isbn);

foreach($valuesArray as $i=>$val){
    $queryArray[$keysArray[$i]] = $val;
}
print_r($queryArray);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [isbn10] => 234234
    [isbn13] => 777777
)
```

Now if you only pass one param

```
$isbn = '234234';
$keysArray = ['isbn10', 'isbn13'];
$valuesArray = explode(';', $isbn);

foreach($valuesArray as $i=>$val){
    $queryArray[$keysArray[$i]] = $val;
}
print_r($queryArray);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [isbn10] => 234234
)
```

> But this does leave a lot of potential for problems as mentioned in the comments, like is it correct that the single param should be placed in `isbn10` and also what happens of there are 3 parameter passed like `123;456;789'